# awk - take a random line from one file, and combine it with lines from another file, output to third file

Tags: arrays, variables, awk

In the problem below I can obtain a random line from file1 using awk, and I can edit file2 using awk, if I simply write a fixed string into the outfile, but if I want to use a random line from file1 instead of a fixed string, then I am stuck. I do not know how to insert the awk code that gets the random line, into the code that edits file2 (or an equivalent approach that does the same job).

file1:

```
    string1_^%"$"£xxXF%
    string2-$^^!dV"$&"}
    string3~£""!&vhTT[@
    string4_%^c!}[&(SR#
    string5_$%&<[*^"!"H
    string6_$$£<[*~)!£H
```

file2:

```
    @ data1 line1, unique text follows
    data1 line2, unique text follows
    @ data2 line1, unique text follows
    data2 line2, unique text follows
    @ data3 line1, unique text follows
    data3 line2, unique text follows
    @ data4 line1, unique text follows
    data4 line2, unique text follows
```

Desired output:

outfile:

```
    $ data1 line1, unique text follows
    data1 line2, unique text follows
    fixed_text_inserted
    string2-$^^!dV"$&"}
    $ data2 line1, unique text follows
    data2 line2, unique text follows
    fixed_text_inserted
    string6_$$£<[*~)!£H
    $ data3 line1, unique text follows
    data3 line2, unique text follows
    fixed_text_inserted
    string3~£""!&vhTT[@
    $ data4 line1, unique text follows
    data4 line2, unique text follows
    fixed_text_inserted
    string6_$$£<[*~)!£H
```

fixed_text_inserted is always the same, just a string (no spaces or tabs)

The last (i.e. 4th) line of each record is a random line from file1 (these lines contain special characters, e.g. $£%"'%^, and text, but no spaces or tabs).

The random choice is with replacement, as in my example outfile, where string6_$$£<[*~)!£H} happens to have been chosen more than once.

I have around 400 of file2 and each is big (~1GB), and so it is easy for me to write a script that is too slow, but I am having a problem implementing this with awk.

Here is an idea of the two awk commands that each do almost half of what I want:

First gets a random line from file1:

`awk 'BEGIN{srand();} {a[NR]=$0} END{for(i=1; i<=5000; i++){x=int(rand()*NR) + 1}}' file 1`

Then use that random line in the creation of new file (outfile) from file2:

`awk 'BEGIN {getline rlines; RS = "#" ; FS = "\n"} NR > 1 {print $1"\n"$2"\n"; printf rlines[NR]; printf "\n"}' file2 > outfile`

I doubt that merging these two lines is the way to do this; these awk lines are just to give an idea (I hope) of what I am trying to do.

I am posting this not only because I am stuck, but because the problem touches on a generic issue of how to work on multiple files in awk and how to define complex variables therein. There are examples on line, but they treat these things separately.

Thank you to anyone who has any suggestions, I haven't yet got the feel for "awk thinking".

Comment: Consider using [shuf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/shuf.1.html) instead to get a random line from a file: `shuf -n 1 file1`

Comment: Wait, are you trying to get 1 random line or 5000? Can you explain what your end goal is? What should the final file(s) look like?

Comment: I am sorry for the ambiguity. I need one random line per record in file2, because one line in file2 needs to be replaced per record in generating the outfile. There are 5000 records in file2, so if I was using an array as the source of my lines then it would need  5000 rows. The bash array example is only there to illustrate the error I got when trying to use a bash array in awk.

Comment: outfile would contain 5000 records like this:  <br/> # first line of record from file2  <br/> Second line of record from file2 <br/> Third line of record randomly chosen from file1 <br/> # first line of next record .... until 5000th record.

Comment: I have edited the question into a input / desired output format. In doing so I included all of the changes to file2 that I need to make. Consequently, some of the early answers to my original post no longer seem fitting, but of course that is my fault.

Comment: The `@`s at the start of some lines in your input file2 became `$`s in your output - if that's a mistake and they should remain `@`s then please fix the output to remove any confusion and so people don't waste time including that transformation in their answers.

Comment: @Ed Morton thank you for checking. It is not a mistake, every @  becomes a $, but not if it is an @ in a line from file 1. The @s that need replacing are the ones at the beginning of every first line of each pair of lines in file2 (i.e. they are regularly spaced, every other line, as in my example input file2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This inserts a randomly selected line from file1 into file2 at the third position. This should be very fast for this task.

```
$ sed "3i$(shuf -n1 file1)" file2 > file3
```

If you want to insert every third line, with possibly repeating the random line, also trimming the random string at the non-alphanum boundary.  For repeating the same for more than one input file, this should do...

```
$ awk 'BEGIN   {srand()}
       NR==FNR {sub(/[^[:alnum:]].*/,""); a[NR]=$0; size++; next}
       FNR==1  {close(f); f=FILENAME".outfile"} 
               {print > f} 
       !(FNR%2){print a[int(rand()*size)+1] > f}' randomvals file1 file3 ...
```

provide the random values file first and to be updated files the next. Will create ".updated" appended versions for each input file.

Comment: Thank you, yes shuf is very convenient. I am using shuf in my bash solution to this problem. I can make a bash array of 5000 random lines and go through the array using the elements as the third line in each record. It works fine, but it is very slow. I find awk is faster than bash, in general, and maybe for this job too.

Comment: Not sure why the 5,000 is relevant here.   This inserts a randomly selected line from file1 into file2 at the third position.   This should be the fastest solution for this scenario.  Are you inserting more than one random line into file2? Perhaps your question is not explained in full.

Comment: `+1` for the awk solution. `a[NR]=$0; size++` = `a[++size]=$0`.  You should change `f=FILENAME".outfile"` to  `close(f); f=FILENAME".outfile"` so it'll work no matter how many output files are generated even if you're not using GNU awk. Without that you'll get a "too many open files" error after creating a dozen or so output files.

Comment: @knovice sounds like you should read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) to understand the issues and why an awk solution would be orders of magnitude faster than a bash read loop.

Comment: Thank you @EdMorton I am sorry for creating further misunderstanding. I posted the question, and I am trying awk, precisely because I know a bash loop is too slow. That's what I meant by "it is easy for me to write a script that is too slow".  I suspect that the job can be done in one invocation of awk, but I haven't yet figured out how. Whenever I have converted a bash loop to an awk solution it has indeed been much faster, like donkey versus cheetah.

Comment: @knovice no problem, now you know how to ask a good question for next time and know why a shell read loop is so slow and hard to get right. This good answer from karakfa shows you how to do it all in 1 awk script for all of your input files at once.

Comment: thank you @karakfa I can use that approach to speed things up greatly.

Comment: and thank you @EdMorton for illustrating construction of a useful question, and the open files error fix.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it boils down to replacing every third line of one file with a random line from a second file. That's pretty easy to do with a combination of `awk` and `shuf`:

```
$ cat file1.txt
#a
b
c
#d
e
f
#g
h
i
$ cat file2.txt
1
2
3
4
5
6
$ awk 'NR == FNR { lines[NR]=$0; next }
       { if (FNR % 3) print; else print lines[++i] }' <(shuf file2.txt) file1.txt
#a
b
6
#d
e
2
#g
h
1
```

Read a shuffled version of the replacement line file into an array, and then for every third line of the record file, print out a replacement line instead of the original.

---

And for fun, a bash equivalent that uses a coproc to access the shuffled files instead of storing them in an array.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# replace.sh originalfile replacementlinesfile
coproc shuf { shuf "$2"; read; }
declare -i i=1
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [ $((i++ % 3)) -eq 0 ]; then
        IFS= read -r -u "${shuf[0]}" line
    fi
    echo "$line"
done < "$1"
echo "done" >&"${shuf[1]}"
wait "$shuf_PID"
```

Comment: Thank you, this: `awk 'NR == FNR { lines[NR]=$0; next }
       { if (FNR % 3) print; else print lines[++i] }' <(shuf file2.txt) file1.txt` gives me enough of an idea of the syntax and the approach to use. My fundamental problem was running through an array and a file in concert (in awk) and working on the lines together, before printing the result to a new file. The files are big (~1 GB) so my usual bash methods were slow. Thanks again.